# Can itemize contain listings in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings

So I'm working on a project and I wanted to build a list of `listings` in order to show how the code written inside them is used. However when I compile the following code I get a lot of errors. Why is that the case ? If what I did simply isn't possible, then what options do I have for doing what I intended ?

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\fontsize{6.5}{8.0}
\selectfont
\frametitle{Das if/then-Paket}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] text1 \end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] text2 \end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] text3 \end{lstlisting}
}
{   
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] text4 \end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] text5 \end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] text6 \end{lstlisting} 
}
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
```

The error I get is : `Undefined control sequence. \begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] text1`

Comment: I get no error if I put your snippet in a minimal example and load the needed packages. (I don't get the intended layout, but that's another question).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmm weird... I cannot run it without said error. But your solution below works fine!

Comment: As you didn't provide a complete example it is not possible to tell you what you did wrong - that's one of the problem with such snippets.

Comment: Okay.. I get that but since it's for a presentation I'm not really sure how much I'm allowed to post here.

Comment: You should try to create a complete but *small* example by removing everything that is not related to the problem.

Comment: Good.. I'll remember that for the next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the listings content on a new line. But beside this it works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings,multicol,tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\fontsize{6.5}{8.0}
\selectfont
\frametitle{Das if/then-Paket}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] 
\section # % text1 
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] 
text2 \end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] 
text3 
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX]
text4 
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] 
text5 
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] 
text6 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]